# What's the point of the "api" path segment in newly created ..net core API project

Tags: rest, asp.net-core

When I create a new API only .Net Core project the default route is [Route("api/[controller]")] resulting in something like 
http://localhost:1234/api/customers. When it comes time to deploy as say my service api.wonderfulweb.com, then it looks like this api.wonderfulweb.com/api/customers.

I can only see the point of having the api path segment if you're sharing the same project with say the UI controllers. It seems to me like this default for a single API project is wrong and it should be [Route("[controller]")] or [Route("v1/[controller]")]?

Comment: Selecting a particular project type merely scaffolds different files (i.e. an API-style controller vs. an MVC-style controller vs. Razor Pages). Everything is still ASP.NET Core; there's is no real meaningful difference between any of the sub project types. In other words, even though you scaffolded an API project, you can add some Razor Pages, or maybe a few MVC controllers. The scaffold employs safe route naming defaults so things don't step on each others toes. As Nick says, you can always change it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this and I understand what you're saying, however if I'm creating an API project then that's what it is, not a hybrid one. If it morphs into that then you can change the paths accordingly.. Maybe I'm being a bit pedantic but as I see it the default for an API should be: api.xyz.com/v1/customers/abc rather than api.xyz.com/api/v1/customers/abc

Comment: The good of the many outweighs the few. Designing frameworks is hard, because there's nearly as many varied scenarios as there are developers facing them. The goal is to cause the least friction possible, and that means putting an "api" prefix so route conflicts don't happen out of the box. It's also why this is easily changeable. Honestly, this is really not much of a hoop to jump through.

Comment: FYI it looks like Microsoft are removing the api segment from path for new api template in [3.0.0-preview5](/aspnet/AspNetCore/milestone/38)  [GitHub post here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7285)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segment is simply an example. You can feel free to name it what you want, or even drop the segment completely.

Different projects have different goals. Some also render pages and some only consist of an API. The ASP.NET Core team decided on something they found a safe default. But, like you mentioned, for a single API project this might not be necessary. Not wrong perse. Just not necessary.

If you feel the default for API projects should change, you can raise an issue on the [ASP.NET Core GitHub project](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore). Just make sure you mention that you mean the default Visual Studio template.

Comment: "Different projects have different goals", but if I've selected an API project than that is pretty obvious (i think) what the intention is. I was thinking of raising an issue but didn't know where to look...thanks.

Comment: @LeeAlexander very true. Honestly, I’ve always removed the /api segment from all my api projects. Can you post a link to your issue here if you’ve made one? I’m interested in the response it gets.

Comment: I've created and issue on the ASP.NET project you can find it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7285)